# Github - how many developers are working on a public project?

Tags: github

Does anyone know if there's a way to view the number of developers working on a public project on Github?  I'd like to know how active a project is before deciding whether or not to use the software.  I can see the number of people watching the project, and the number of people who forked.  If I browse the source, I can see the names of users who have committed changes to the project.  What I'm hoping to find is a list (or total number) of all those users who have pushed back commits.

Comment: Why is this question being closed? It's certainly not off-topic.

Comment: To quote the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq): _"If your question covers software tools commonly used by programmers then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you're on a repository page, click the Graphs Tab, then Contributors. You will then see a graph for each contributor and their level of contribution.

eg here is CakePHP's contributor graph: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/graphs/contributors

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the exact number of contributors, it's in the *Impact* tab that you need to look.

The same example with CakePHP: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/graphs/impact
It shows: *X authors over Y weeks*.